# how to create exe of a c file

Tags: executable

i have created a small project in c and want to create its portable exe file.
how can i do that??

Comment: Compilers do a .exe when they compile the code under windows.

Answer (score 6):

[MSVC++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/visualc/default.aspx)

[BCC](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20633)

[MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)

Knock yourself out.